# SQL - Identifiy changes of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

[image]

ChangeType = 1 => Record creation

ChangeType = 3 => Record deletion

I'd like to determine which operation I have to do on records. If a record was created and then deleted (line 1 and 2). I'd like to flag them as 'Ignore' (in *Operation* column). If only creation happened, flag it as 'Create' and if only deletion, flag it as 'Delete'.

Final result will look like this:

1----Ignore

2----Ignore

3----Create

4----Delete

5----Create

Line 2 occured **after** line 1. If before, mark line 1 as Create and 2 as Ignore)

How it can be done? Cursor?

Thank you

Table creation script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
[EntityKey] [int] NULL,
[CompositeEntityKey] [int] NULL,
[DynEntityTypeKey] [int] NULL,
[ChangeType] [tinyint] NULL,
[CreatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
[FinalOperation] [nchar](10) NULL) ON [PRIMARY] GO
```

Insert:

```
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([EntityKey], [CompositeEntityKey], [DynEntityTypeKey], [ChangeType], [CreatedOn], [FinalOperation]) VALUES (12345, 54321, 3, 1, CAST(N'2022-03-20T11:29:19.230' AS DateTime), N'          ') GO
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([EntityKey], [CompositeEntityKey], [DynEntityTypeKey], [ChangeType], [CreatedOn], [FinalOperation]) VALUES (12345, 54321, 3, 3, CAST(N'2022-03-20T11:30:19.230' AS DateTime), N'          ') GO
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([EntityKey], [CompositeEntityKey], [DynEntityTypeKey], [ChangeType], [CreatedOn], [FinalOperation]) VALUES (12345, 98765, 3, 1, CAST(N'2022-03-21T11:29:19.230' AS DateTime), N'          ') GO
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([EntityKey], [CompositeEntityKey], [DynEntityTypeKey], [ChangeType], [CreatedOn], [FinalOperation]) VALUES (12345, 14523, 3, 3, CAST(N'2022-03-19T11:29:19.230' AS DateTime), N'          ') GO
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([EntityKey], [CompositeEntityKey], [DynEntityTypeKey], [ChangeType], [CreatedOn], [FinalOperation]) VALUES (14523, 98765, 3, 1, CAST(N'2022-03-20T14:29:19.230' AS DateTime), N'          ') GO
```

Comment: We can't copy code from images. Could you please post it as text, i.e. CREATE TABLE and INSERT sample values statements instead? Also, how are you defining  "immediately" - Next record, some time period like X seconds? If it's a period of time, how much time?

Comment: and what have you tried so far? But yes, this looks like a CURSOR job

Comment: @SOS Question edited. 

Immendiately is no matter, i meant then.

Comment: @Fandango68 I tried a cursor, yes. But only managed to update the first line.

We must analyze each group of entities (EntityKey and CompositeEntityKey) and determine what exactly to do for each of them. There may be a series of operations that have been performed, so take the last one, yes, but not always. And especially mark others with Ignore etc..

Comment: You're getting into the dark arts of SQL look-ahead! LOL... read this. https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-read-ahead-mechanism-concept-performance-gains/ Also this https://towardsdatascience.com/6-sql-tricks-every-data-scientist-should-know-f84be499aea5

Comment: Read up on PARTITION OVER and you'll have some idea of what you need, and it may be solveable without a cursor. I avoid cursors as much as possible

Comment: It is unclear why you would use `Ignore` for lines 1 and 2, and `Delete` for line 4. It would be much simpler to set them all to `Delete` (which is the status of the last line.

Comment: @SOS, let's say yes. We can imagine that a record has been created, then deleted involuntarily and therefore recreated afterwards. The first creation should therefore be marked as "Ignore", the deletion as "Ignore", and the second creation as "Create".

So, you have to know what is the last operation performed by the pair and mark the others as "Ignore". Except that in the case where there was creation then deletion (as in the example above), ignore the two lines. I can't delete something that doesn't exist in the other system.

Comment: @Luuk Line 4 exists in the second system. It must therefore be deleted there, following the deletion in the first system.

Lines 1 and 2 do not exist in the second system. So I can't delete this pair. And no interest in creating and then deleting...

Comment: @Fandango68, I'm no SQL expert, unfortunately. I know it's something quite complex, I've never done it before.

I did some tests, several even, but I know that it's not great and that there may be big performance problems.

And the problem, as usual, is that it's urgent :(

Comment: @MosheHAYUN - So the ordering of actions are dictated by the EntityKey, CompositeEntryKey and CreatedOn grouping?  Maybe you could use use LAG/LEAD to examine the state of the prev/next row ? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=964b8524e555e361b8f234a7be0a8169

Comment: @MosheHAYUN: "Lines 1 and 2 do not exist in the second system."  How do you know, FOR SURE, that they do not exist?  Deleting them should cause no harm...   I think you should consider all rows with Status=1, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=31fe9619e179fb26347c73b759655031

Comment: ^^ That approach sounds safer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CTE maybe like this ([result here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5112d1cb55ba2b260819fb6e713ae7d2))

```
with t1 as (
select *,
lead(ChangeType) over (partition by EntityKey,CompositeEntityKey order by EntityKey,CompositeEntityKey ,createdon) as next_type,
lag(ChangeType) over (partition by EntityKey,CompositeEntityKey order by EntityKey,CompositeEntityKey ,createdon)  as previous_type 
from mytable
)
select t1.*,
case 
   when next_type is null and previous_type is null then
      case changetype when 1 then 'create' when 3 then 'delete' end
   when next_type = 3 and changetype = 1 then 'ignore'
   when previous_type = 1 and changetype = 3 then 'ignore'
end as operation
from t1
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating the records based on `Status` seems to be a nice option:

These are the last (based on CreatedOn) records per EntityKey,CompositeEntityKey group.

```
select 
   entityKey,
   CompositeEntityKey,
   DynEntityTypeKey,
   ChangeType,
   CreatedOn,
   CASE WHEN MAX(CreatedOn) OVER (PARTITION By EntityKey,CompositeEntityKey ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC)=CreatedOn
     THEN 1
     ELSE 0
     END Status
from MyTable
order by 1,2;
```

output:

| entityKey | CompositeEntityKey | DynEntityTypeKey | ChangeType | CreatedOn | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 14523 | 3 | 3 | 2022-03-19 11:29:19.230 | 1 |
| 12345 | 54321 | 3 | 3 | 2022-03-20 11:30:19.230 | 1 |
| 12345 | 54321 | 3 | 1 | 2022-03-20 11:29:19.230 | 0 |
| 12345 | 98765 | 3 | 1 | 2022-03-21 11:29:19.230 | 1 |
| 14523 | 98765 | 3 | 1 | 2022-03-20 14:29:19.230 | 1 |

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ed3773f22d7d23905965aaed285b85c9)